# How can I call a function in a template based on a component?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

This is part of my template:

```html
<!-- This is the one I want! -->
<label>{{l10n('hallo') | translate}}</label>
```

If my Component has a function l10n its no problem to call the l10n-function

```html
<label>{{cmp.l10n('hallo') | translate}}</label>
```

But that's not what I want - if possible I want `l10n(<string>)`, somehow a global function for this template...

In AngularJS to achieve something linke this they add a function to the Controller-Scope: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466994/504184

My problem here is that I don't have a Controller - I'm in a Component...
Second thing is that the Scope in AngularDart is quite different compared to the Scope in AngularJS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the Scope in your Component and add the function.

```
@Component(selector: 'my-comp')
class Comp {
  Comp(Scope scope) {
    scope.context['l10n'] = (str) => "Boo[$str]";
  }
}
```

However, we are thinking about removing this feature in an upcoming version of AngularDart.

Comment: Cool!!!!! Now my <label class="col-md-3 control-label">{{l10n('Projectname:') | translate}}</label> works like a charm. Thanks. Please!!!! don't remove this feature or if so replace it by something better :-) In this case better would be to have the l10n-function (my userdefined function) in something like an AppController - so that it is available for the whole WebApp. Would be cool + continue with your great work!

Comment: I think it's since Angular 0.14 but now gives me: -- start -- Observer reaction functions should not change model. 
These watch changes were detected: 
These observe changes were detected: l10n("Description:"): -- end -- Here is my l10n-Function: http://goo.gl/u1FOph. It does not modify the model - it just return an L10N-object that should be handled by translate. Any ideas?

Comment: OK - It's Angular 0.14. I downgraded to 0.13. The same - but it worked until a few days ago????

Comment: If I use a const-constructor ( scope.context['l10n'] = (final str) => const L10N("Hallo");) the error message disappears but this is not really a practical solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

James answer was right before Angular 1.0 - now its even simpler.

```dart
class MyComponent {
    ...
    L10N tr(final String text) {
      return new L10N(text);
      }
}
```

```html
<label class="medium">{{tr('Projectname:') | translate}}</label>
```

Thats it!